# The [version] is outdated

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) does not appear useful to me, even with 2000+ questions and 13 followers and therefore I suggest to burninate it. Who subscribes to a tag like that?

Comment: There's also [tag:versions]. There are probably quite a few questions tagged with [tag:version] and [tag:versions] that should get [tag:versioning] instead.

Comment: Looks like [tag:revision] must also go.

Answer (score 10):

Obviously a meta tag, additionally poorly defined. The tag [release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/release) is also in some cases used exactly like [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) (although in most cases it's used to indicate problems with various release operations/processes, meta tag as well).

There are also tags [versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versions) (no wiki at all) which should be burninated as well. [version-numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-numbering) doesn't look good as well.

At least [version-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control) seems to be used more consistently.

Answer (score 5):

[version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version)

Usage guidance:

> Version defines an unique state of a computer software or a file.

Tag info

> Versions and version control systems are widely used in software industry to keep track of different versions of a piece of software.
>
> Following processes and techniques are often used in computer software engineering to keep track of different versions:
>
> - Software versioning
> - Revision control
> - Versioning file systems
>
> Software versioning is the process of assigning either unique version names or unique version numbers to unique states of computer software.
>
> At a fine-grained level, revision control is often used for keeping track of incrementally different versions of electronic information, whether or not this information is actually computer software.
>
> One of the forms of revision control is a versioning file system. Such a system is any computer file system which allows a computer file to exist in several versions at the same time.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   Yes it does. But it's not unambigous since it describes three very different concepts.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   The tag lists three different usages of this tag, and they are all on topic. But as I said, they have nothing to do with each other.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   It does if used correctly, but at a quick glance, that's often not the case.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Since it describes three very different concepts, definitely not.

There is one tag: [version-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control) that could replace one of these cases listed in the tag description. I tried to find tags for software-versioning and versioning filesystems, but I did not find any. I did find the tag [filesystems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesystems) which could be used everywhere when you want to ask about versioning filesystems.

All three use cases for this tag is on topic and relevant. But there is absolutely no reason to group them together into a single tag, since they are so different from each other.

The tag is often used in a way that is neither useful, nor listed on the tag description. I saw plenty of questions where it was used simply because they were using a specific version of something, such as [c89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c89) or wanted to update [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode) from 9.2 to 10.2.1. And I saw a bunch of questions where I could not understand the purpose of the tag at all.

I suggest burninating this tag and replacing it with [version-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control) and [filesystems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesystems). If needed, tags like [versioning-filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versioning-filesystem) and [software-versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-versioning) could be created.