# We have the wrong [version]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

The [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) tag has the following description:

> Version defines an unique state of a computer software or a file.

This tag doesn't add much to a question. You can't be an expert in versions, since it's not specific enough. A more specific tag would be [semantic-versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semantic-versioning), but this would only work if the question is about versioning, and many of them aren't, they are about changing the version of something.

I think the [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) tag should be burninated and disambiguated. Let's go through the formal burnination criteria:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   No. Questions with the [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) tag are not *about* versioning, they just involve versions.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   No, since it's not something that is strictly programming-related.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No, since versioning is not something you can learn, it's not a skill. In contrast to [semantic-versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semantic-versioning) which is a versioning standard. But most of the questions aren't event about versioning.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No, since I would expect the tag to be used on questions about versioning, but it's being used on questions that involve versioning.

Questions with this tag that are about a type of versioning should have that tag instead, e.g. [semantic-versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semantic-versioning).

This tag should be removed from questions that just involve versions of something.

Comment: [Revert \[version\] to version 0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349156/revert-version-to-version-0) [The \[version\] of this tag is old](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251012/the-version-of-this-tag-is-old)